# Dimension Error while using LSTM after Convolutional neural network in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In keras 1.2.2, I have made a dataset which has these dimensions:

```
X_train: (2000, 100, 32, 32, 3) 
y_train: (2000,1)
```

Here, 2000 is the number of instances (batches of data), 100 is the number of samples in each batch, 32 is the image rows and cols, and 3 is the number of channels (RGB).

I have written this code which applies an LSTM after a CNN, however, I get this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

This is my code:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input ,Dense, Dropout, Activation, LSTM
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.pooling import GlobalAveragePooling1D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Model


import numpy as np

timesteps=100;
number_of_samples=2500;
nb_samples=number_of_samples;
frame_row=32;
frame_col=32;
channels=3;

nb_epoch=1;
batch_size=timesteps;

data= np.random.random((2500,timesteps,frame_row,frame_col,channels))
label=np.random.random((2500,timesteps,1))

X_train=data[0:2000,:]
y_train=label[0:2000]

X_test=data[2000:,:]
y_test=label[2000:,:]

#%%

model=Sequential();                          

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=X_train.shape[2:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))


model.add(Dense(35, input_shape=(timesteps,512), name="first_dense" ));
#model.add(Dense(1, name="test_dense"));         

model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, name="lstm_layer"));

#%%
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1), name="time_distr_dense_one"))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="global_avg"))

#%%

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
#%%
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Please post the error of the LSTM then :)

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try exchanging each `Convolution2D(...)` to:

```
TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(...))
```

You need to let your model know that your data is sequential and you want to apply some layer to each element in your sequence. This is what `TimeDistributed` wrapper is for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `fit()` is the right method to use? I would use `train_on_batch` since your training data is already split in batches.

To better control your input_shape, I would advise you to explicitely define it in your first layer. Instead of `X_train.shape[1:]`, use `(32,32,3)` to avoid any surprises.

Does this help you?

Comment: since `train_on_batch` applies gradient updates only for one batch, should I make a loop and call `train_on_batch` for all batches?

Comment: Indeed if you already splitted the data by batches you should loop over them and feed them one by one :) otherwise, the fit() method can split your data into batches automatically. So you could feed all the 200000 images in one array (200000,32,32,3) and specify batch_size to be 100, it will recreate your (2000,100,32,32,3) array. Don't forget to specify the "shuffle" parameter to be True or False if you want the samples to be shuffled before creating batches at each epoch.

Comment: How did you prepare your dataset? did you use imagedatagenerator?

Answer (score 0):

Output dimension of LSTM should be the same with your timesteps.
Try this:

```
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=timesteps, return_sequences=True))
```

It works for me.